# How do I navigate through a facebook $graphObject array and sort it

Tags: php, facebook, sorting, facebook-graph-api

So I've been playing around with the Facebook API and have found that it's not easy! It's very hard to get a grip of it all. So I've managed to get the users id, name, email, friends, movies, and music.

`/me?fields=id,name,email, friends.limit(5), movies.limit(5), music.limit(5)`

But I found that it doesn't actually return the most useful data. It will return the data in any random  order. Which is annoying. I was wondering if there is a way to sort the ***Movies*** and ***Music*** based on the likes (Most likes to least likes)?

At this stage all I've been able to do is print the users data using `print_f($graphObject, 1)`. It would be really usefull if I could sort the Movies and Music based on the likes those pages have.

#### I'll add my code so everyone can see where im upto with the FB api - As you'll see, not very far. But I want to get to know it a lot more. It's very useful!

```
// start session
session_start();

// init app with app id and secret
FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication( 'App_ID','SECRET_KEY' );

// login helper with redirect_uri
$helper = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper( 'http://localhost/PHP_Advanced/Facebook/' );

// see if a existing session exists
if ( isset( $_SESSION ) && isset( $_SESSION['fb_token'] ) ) {
  // create new session from saved access_token
  $session = new FacebookSession( $_SESSION['fb_token'] );
  
  // validate the access_token to make sure it's still valid
  try {
    if ( !$session->validate() ) {
      $session = null;
    }
  } catch ( Exception $e ) {
    // catch any exceptions
    $session = null;
  }
}  

if ( !isset( $session ) || $session === null ) {
  // no session exists
  
  try {
    $session = $helper->getSessionFromRedirect();
  } catch( FacebookRequestException $ex ) {
    // When Facebook returns an error
    // handle this better in production code
    print_r( $ex );
  } catch( Exception $ex ) {
    // When validation fails or other local issues
    // handle this better in production code
    print_r( $ex );
  }
  
}

// see if we have a session
if ( isset( $session ) ) {
  
  // save the session
  $_SESSION['fb_token'] = $session->getToken();
  // create a session using saved token or the new one we generated at login
  $session = new FacebookSession( $session->getToken() );
  
  // graph api request for user data
  $request = new FacebookRequest(
   $session, 
   //Add permissions to this - All gets returned as json object
    'GET', '/me?fields=id,name,email, friends.limit(5), movies.limit(5), music.limit(5)' 
    );


  $response = $request->execute();
  // get response
  $graphObject = $response->getGraphObject()->asArray();
  
  //Store basic user info to then put into database
  $userID = $graphObject['id'];
  $userName = $graphObject['name'];
  $userEmail = $graphObject['email'];
  echo "Hello ".$userName;

    
  echo "hello  " . $data;
  // print profile data
  echo '<pre>' . print_r( $graphObject, 1 ) . '</pre>';
  
  // print logout url using session and redirect_uri (logout.php page should destroy the session)
  echo '<a href="' . $helper->getLogoutUrl( $session, 'http://localhost/PHP_Advanced/Facebook/' ) . '">Logout</a>';
  
} else {
  // show login url
  echo '<a href="' . $helper->getLoginUrl( array( 'email', 'user_friends','user_likes' ) ) . '">Login</a>';
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `{likes, name}` to return likes count along with movie/music data.

Eg:

```
me?fields=id,name,email,movies.limit(5){likes,name},music.limit(5){likes,name}
```

After that you can sort json data based on likes.

Sample code:

```
<?php 
    $output = '{"id":"100004827362122","name":"FirstName LastName","email":"email@domain.com","movies":{"data":[{"likes":725577,"name":"Canal D2M","id":"253861394671560"},{"likes":4514156,"name":"UTV Motion Pictures","id":"82457488277"},{"likes":48573,"name":"Unfreedom","id":"204640696244906"},{"likes":13677504,"name":"Star Wars","id":"263361123833008"},{"likes":246922,"name":"Shudh Desi Endings","id":"162737470589326"}],"paging":{"cursors":{"before":"MjUzODYxMzk0NjcxNTYw","after":"MTYyNzM3NDcwNTg5MzI2"},"next":"https://graph.facebook.com/v2.2/100004827362122/movies?pretty=0&fields=likes,name&limit=5&after=MTYyNzM3NDcwNTg5MzI2"}},"music":{"data":[{"likes":2215,"name":"WDL","id":"1472840169599887"},{"likes":113860,"name":"Daniel Waples - Hang in Balance","id":"161974437185126"},{"likes":229799,"name":"KEXP","id":"9054273111"},{"likes":1276105,"name":"The Movement","id":"253878101400547"},{"likes":13294164,"name":"Virgin Radio Lebanon","id":"275155342593810"}],"paging":{"cursors":{"before":"MTQ3Mjg0MDE2OTU5OTg4Nw==","after":"Mjc1MTU1MzQyNTkzODEw"},"next":"https://graph.facebook.com/v2.2/100004827362122/music?pretty=0&fields=likes,name&limit=5&after=Mjc1MTU1MzQyNTkzODEw"}}}';
    $output = json_decode($output, true);

    $movies = $output['movies']['data'];

    function sortData($a, $b)
    {
        if ($a == $b) {
            return 0;
        }
        return ($a > $b) ? -1 : 1;
    }

    usort($movies, 'sortData');

    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($movies);
?>
```

Comment: I doubt that this will give you the most liked movies and music though. The limit is likely applied on a data set that is _not_ sorted by that criterion – so all you will achieve here is to get the number of likes for five movies and music pieces that have been selected rather “randomly”.

Comment: @CBroe - True. Is there a way to get the whole list of ***Movies*** and ***Music***  instead of just getting 1 page worth of them? Even without the ***.limit(5)*** It would only display a limited amount (Not the whole list). If I could get the whole list then I could use this ***sortData() function*** on the whole list.

Comment: There is a default limit that gets applied if you don’t specify one yourself, and also a maximum number of items you can get with one request. After that, you will have to use pagination to request the next “page” of results. (See API documentation for an explanation as to how pagination works.)

Comment: In that case you have to paginate through whole data set, save data in variable and sort them. Sadly, Graph api doesn't provide data sorted on basis of number of likes.